# How to apply pagination & offset in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination, offset

I am searching user with name and email and below is my body request:

```
{
 "email": "shah",
 "name": "shah",
}
```

I want to apply pagination & offset in this API which will take two more parameters which offset and paginate which will search accordingly and my body request will be something like this:

```
{
 "email": "shah",
 "name": "shah",
 "offset": 1,
 "paginate": 1
}
```

My code:

```php
$pram = $request->name;
$email= $request->email;
$roleId= $request->role_id;

$results = User::where('email','like', '%' . $email . '%')
    ->WhereHas('userBasicInfo', function ($query) use ($pram) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
            ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%');
    })->with(['userBasicInfo' => function ($query) use ($pram) {
        $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
            ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%');
    }])->get()->toArray();
```

How can I apply pagination and offset in my above API which takes two more parameters.

Comment: What happens when you delete `->get()->toArray();` and set `->paginate(15)`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "which takes two more parameters" ?

Comment: you need to use `skip` and `take`, something like this: `...->skip(num_recs_to_skip)->take(num_recs_to_take)->get();`

Comment: Just replace get()->toArray() to paginate(15)..Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$results ['result'] = User::where('email','like', '%' . $email . '%')
    ->WhereHas('userBasicInfo', function ($query) use ($pram) {
    $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
        ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%');
    })->with(['userBasicInfo' => function ($query) use ($pram) {
    $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
        ->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $pram . '%');
    }])->paginate(6);

    return view('Your View PHP', $results);
```

Comment: i dont want to remove toArray

Comment: $results['results'] this is a array formate. so if you execute the query every data will come inside of array => $results['results']